# React Checking nested JSON Key before rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am getting data back from MarvelAPI and there is no guarentee whether or not the key that I am accessing is available.
So I am checking each key with an if statement before accessing them.

As you can see the code below looks very ugly. Is there is a much better / standard way of doing this?

```
renderCharacterNames(detail) {
    console.log('detail', detail)
    if (detail && detail[0] && detail[0].characters && detail[0].characters.items && detail[0].characters.items.length > 0) {
        return (
            <div>
                {detail[0].characters.items.map((obj, index) => {
                    return <li key={index}>{obj.name}</li>
                })}
            </div>
        )
    } else {
        return <div>No Character Name</div>
    }
}

renderComicDetail() {
    var detail = this.props.comicDetail;
    if (!detail) {
        return (
            <div>No Data Yet (loading?)</div>
        )
    }
    return (
        <div>
            {this.renderCharacterNames(detail)}
        </div>
    )
}
```

[image: console]

Comment: is there a reason why you're only accessing `detail[0]`?

Comment: The API seems to always return an array of length 1 with all the data contained. So I am just accessing it like that for now. This data comes back when I query the API with comiId = someId, as each ID corresponds to one comic, I think accessing detail[0] would be reasonable (for now). Note that I can change it so that it can handle more cases, but that is not the main question I have here. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Set [default properties](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#defaultprops) for each key, so you don't have to worry about them being undefined. I'd default name to "", and characters to an empty array.

Detail.defaultProps = {
  name: '',
  characters: []
};